# Windows Server 2008 R2 user dial-in tab error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have no problem creating a new user in AD on my Windows Server 2008 R2, but when I go to edit the dial-in properties I receive the following error: "Could not load dial-in profile for this user because: Access Denied".

Remote Registry Service is running and both HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg and HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg\AllowedPaths have read permissions for Local Service account.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Sandro

Comment: Did you checked this thread out?  
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/678bd1aa-6b4c-4597-a613-253c0e46e4ab/why-cant-i-change-the-dialin-settings-within-ad?forum=winserverDS

Comment: Yes, I read that thread but my problem is slightly different: I cannot access the Dial-In tab, so I cannot change any settings inside